# Qml blur effect on listview

Tags: c++, qt, qml

i want to add blur effect at the bottom of listview like this:

[image]

i wrote this code with Qml but does not work correctly.
could you please tell me where is the problem and how can i fix this ?

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 480
    height: 520
    visible: true
    title: qsTr('Blur List')
    color: 'black'
    ScrollView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        Column {
            spacing: 15
            width: view.width - 10
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            Repeater {
                model: 30
                delegate: Rectangle {
                    width: view.width - 5
                    height: 50
                    radius: 10
                    color: 'orange'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ShaderEffectSource {
        id: shader
        width: view.width
        height: 80
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        sourceItem: view
        sourceRect: Qt.rect(x, y, width, height)
    }
    FastBlur {
        id: fastBlur
        anchors.fill: shader
        source: shader
        radius: 20
    }
}
```

Comment: *"does not work correctly"* -- What does that mean? Be more specific please.

Comment: You can't blur any qml control like this using FastBlur effect. The only way I can see will be to render image from part of scroll view in the background of app and than set is as a source for FastBlur.

Comment: I cant undrestand your solution. Could you please explain it with code or something like this ? @kluszon

Comment: It's not so easy, but I have some fast workaround for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfect, but it works. Quick demo of how to do it:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 480
    height: 520
    visible: true
    title: qsTr('Blur List')
    color: 'black'
    ScrollView {
        id: view

        property int rowSpacing: 15
        property int rowHeight: 50

        anchors.fill: parent
        Column {
            spacing: view.rowSpacing
            width: view.width - 10
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            Repeater {
                model: 30
                delegate: Rectangle {
                    width: view.width - 5
                    height: view.rowHeight
                    radius: 10
                    color: 'cyan'
                    Image{
                        id: img
                        anchors.top: parent.top
                        anchors.left: parent.left
                        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                        width: height
                        source: "qrc:/images/image.png"
                    }
                    Text{
                        anchors.top: parent.top
                        anchors.left: img.right
                        anchors.right: parent.right
                        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                        text: "Item number: " + index
                        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Item{
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: view.rowSpacing
        height: view.rowHeight

        LiveBlur{
            source: view
            xPos: 0
            yPos: parent.height
        }

        Text{
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "BOTTOM TEST"
            color: "white"
            font.pointSize: 25
            font.bold: true
        }
    }
}
```

LiveBlur.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Item {
    id: root
    property variant source
    property int xPos
    property int yPos

    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    clip: true

    FastBlur{
        id: blur
        source: root.source
        x: -root.x
        y: -root.y
        width: root.source.width
        height: root.source.height
        radius: 32
    }
}
```

[image]